# Firebase onAuthStateChanged currentUser always null when first load a page React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I think I should ask this question, cause I face some very weird problem.

I have a protected route, `/app`, if user is not login reached this page, redirect to `/auth/login`, so I have this, common Context hooks:

```
const { user, isLoading } = useAuth()

useEffect(() => {

   if (!(user || isLoading)) {
        // HERE REDIRECT TO /auth/login
    }
}, [user, isLoading])

//here make sense
```

Now in my `useAuth()`, I have this:

```
const useAuth = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((currentUser) => {
                setIsLoading(false)
                if (currentUser) {
                    console.log(currentUser)
    
                    //here 
                    getUserFromMyServer(currentUser.uid).then(res => {
                        
                        let userDetails = res.detail 
                        setUser(userDetails) // here will get User data from server

                    }).catch(error => setUser(null))
    
                } else {
                    setUser(null)
                }
            })
        }, [])
    
    
    
    return {
            user,
            isLoading,
            loginWithTwitter, // a function will mention later 
            getTwitterRedirectResult, //a function will mention later
            logout // a function
    }
}
```

This is what I call to server

```
// here is the getUserFromMyServer function in another files, it look like this: 
export const getUserFromMyServer = async () => {
    const path = "/user"
    const firebaseToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()

    console.log(firebaseToken)

    const myInit = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${firebaseToken}`,
        }
    }

    return API.get(apiName, path, myInit) // Here return a promise
}
```

OK, so far is working well. When done login, it will `setUser()`, then will redirect from `/auth/login` to `/app` according to the `user`, this is what I want.

**Now when I implement Sign in with Twitter, it comes in a problem**.

**The behavior:** When done Sign in with Twitter, it redirect to `/app`. Then when `/app` is loaded for 20s like that then it go back to `/auth/login` again. This is keep repeating, non-stop until the browser hang.

Here is my code for Sign in with Twitter.

`useAuth.js` (same file with code above with loginWithTwitter)

```
const [operation, setOperation] = useState('login')

const loginWithTwitter = () => {
        setOperation(type)
        let provider = getTwitterProvider()

        return firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
    }

const getTwitterRedirectResult = () => {
        return firebase
            .auth()
            .getRedirectResult()
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result)

                var credential = result.credential;


                var token = credential.accessToken;
                var secret = credential.secret;
                var twitterHandle = result.additionalUserInfo.username


                if (operation === 'sign-up') {
                    // if sign up, here save to my db
                    createUserInDb(twitterHandle, token, secret).then(res=> {

                        setUser(res.data)
                    }).catch(error => setUser(null))
                }

                if (operation === 'login') {
                    // here get back the user details same as above
                    getUser()
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message)
                setErrorMessage(error.message)
                setUser(null)
            });
    }
```

Then in my `/auth/login` and `/auth/sign-up` I have this code:

```
const Login = () => {
    const { user, getTwitterRedirectResult } = useAuth() // 
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getTwitterRedirectResult() // here call to twitter redirect result 
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user) {
            // code redirect to app 
           router.push('/app')
        }
    })
}
```

So now, when login/sign up with password, is no problem. Once login, go to `/app`. then stay there.

But when sign in with Twitter, it go to `/app`. Stay there for 20s, then it redirect back to `/auth/login`. Basically is infinite loop.

So now my question:

1. What is the correct way to call `getTwitterRedirect` in react? Is it call at `useEffect()` when the page load?
2. How to solve the infinite loop? Done login go to `/app`, then it go back to `/auth/login` again.
3. How to save user data to my own db when getting the result back from `getTwitterRedirect`. So when Sign up I need to create the record, but when login with Twitter, I just need to get back the same record. But right now, it only have 1 function `getTwitterRedirect`, login and sign up also use this. So how can I solve this?

Please someone tell me what I doing wrong, I have totally no clue.

Thanks in advance.